# Avoiding port conflicts between docker-compose.yml configurations?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using Docker for Mac and have 3 different "microservices" in separate repositories which have their own `docker-compose.yml` file. The services themselves don't run in docker but have a `docker-compose.yml` file that is used to bring up databases (e.g. postgresql, minio and redis) used by each service. This makes it easy for me to work on the services in isolation.

However, it is difficult to bring 2 services simultaneously `cd service1 && docker-compose up -d && cd service2 && docker-compose up -d` because of port conflicts. For example, if service1 brings up PostgreSQL and exposes it to port 5432 and service2 wants to do the same, the second `docker-compose up` command will fail.

It would be acceptable for both services to share the same PosgtreSQL container but I'm not sure if it's possible to tell docker-compose "use the database from service1 if it's available or otherwise create a new container".

Another solution would be to ensure each that each service has a unique port, but that can be difficult to keep track of as more and more docker-compose stacks are in use.

Any advice for managing this sort of workflow would be appreciated.

In case that helps, here's how one of my docker-compose.yml files looks like:

```
minio:
  image: minio/minio
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
  volumes:
    - ./test/.minio/data:/export
    - ./test/.minio/config:/root/.minio
  environment:
    - "MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE"
    - "MINIO_SECRET_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY"
    - "MINIO_ENABLE_FSMETA=true"

createbucket:
  image: garland/aws-cli-docker
  links:
    - minio
  command: >
    /bin/sh -c "
      while ! wget -q -s http://minio:9000/minio/login; do sleep 1; done;
      aws configure set default.s3.signature_version s3v4;
      aws configure set default.region us-east-1;
      aws s3api create-bucket \
        --bucket service1-test \
        --endpoint-url=http://minio:9000;
      exit 0;
    "
  environment:
    - "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE"
    - "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY"

db:
  image: postgres:9.5
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"

createdb:
  image: postgres:9.5
  links:
    - db
  command: >
    /bin/bash -c "
      while ! psql --host=db --username=postgres; do sleep 1; done;
      psql --host=db --username=postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE \"service1-test\";';
    "

services:
  image: alpine:3.2
  links:
    - db
    - minio
  command: /bin/true
```

I bring it up with this command: `docker-compose up createdb && docker-compose up createbucket && docker-compose up -d services`

Comment: The problem is you're integrating services on the host with containers, so you don't have many options. You can publish explicit ports, or you can use explicit IP addresses for the container, but either of those will be difficult to manage. If you ran your service as a container too, that would be different - it would run in the same Docker network as its dependencies, and you wouldn't need to publish ports.

Comment: Yes, indeed. As a temporary solution, I created a a shared docker-compose.yml and reference its services through external_links. As I'm using Node.js, I made a npm script that automatically brings up the shared services (https://github.com/blockai/blockai-dc), but it's obviously not a 100% docker-compose only solution.

Comment: The reason I only use docker-compose.yml for databases, is that `npm install` in docker was too slow last time I tried (and I often add/remove dependencies) and nodemon didn't work properly, but maybe I should try again in case this has improved.

Comment: You can try splitting your Dockerfile - just `COPY package.json` in one command and `RUN npm install` as separate instructions before you copy in your whole app source code. Then the layer with the dependencies will be cached, later builds should be fast, but if you change `package.json` the build will see the change and run `npm install` again.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like something you would use [the `extends` directive](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services) for. That would mean creating a fourth `docker-compose.yml` file that ties in your services together, inside which you can redefine shared services as well.

Comment: It looks like support for `extends` has been [dropped in Compose files version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-3)